# How can i make a Jlist automatically scroll down after adding new elements

Tags: java, swing, file, text

Just got a quick question, How can i make a JList automatically scroll to the new element that i've added. Heres an example if i add 4 new elements to a jList. It will just add. normally

Then when i add a 5th element it just adds the element, dosen't scroll down to display it.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: If your JList has a scrallpane you should be able to just dp jlist.setSelected(new file index) and it will scroll down.

Comment: How can i fetch the file index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add the items to the model you can use:

```
list.ensureIndexIsVisible( list.getModel().getSize() -1 )
```